# React Native chat bubble flexbox similar to whatsapp

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a chat view in React Native similar to the Whatsapp UI. 
What I can't wrap my head around is - how to do the time. Here is how it looks in Whatsapp:
[image]

Notice that the time is not on a completely new line by itself, but half a line.

At the same time in the last comment you can see that if the text is long enough, the time is being pushed to a new line.

I've tried several things:

1. Make the bubble relative and then use absolute positioning on the time element. Unfortunately if the text is long enough my time overlaps the text.
2. Make the bubble flexDirection: "row", and then have the text in 1 view and the time in another view. But I can't figure out how to force a wrap when the text is "long enough".

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you share some code please ?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to kind of get what I want. It's not 100% the same as whatsapp, but good enough.

I had the following code:

```
  <View style={{
      margin: 10, marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 0,
      padding: 10, borderRadius: 5, paddingBottom: 10,
      backgroundColor: cropType ? '#93D14C' : '#F1F0F5'
    }}>
        {this.renderContent(comment)}

      <Text
        style={[styles.muted,
          {
            color: constants.FJMUTEDLIGHT,
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            alignSelf: 'flex-end',
            fontSize: 12,
            marginBottom: -5,
            marginTop: 2
          }]}>{moment.utc(comment.created).local().format('HH:mm')}</Text>
    </View>
```

The renderContentHere() function can render Text, but it also can render a complex View containing text. Initially I wanted to figure out how many lines a text has and to figure the width of the lines. This doesn't seem to be possible with React Native since the onLayout property on a Text node can only tell you the width and height of the element, but not if the Text is 2 lines or 3 lines.

So I decided to just measure the View that contains the comment and figure out if it has one or more lines. If it has one line I'm assuming that I can place the time a little higher than normally.

This is what I ended up doing:

```
<View style={{
          margin: 10, marginTop: 10, marginBottom: 0,
          padding: 10, borderRadius: 5, paddingBottom: 10,
          backgroundColor: cropType ? '#93D14C' : '#F1F0F5'
        }}>

          <View style={this.state.oneLine ? {
            // Since we don't know how long the one line is, just in case add 25px padding on the right
            // this way even if we are dealing with a long line of text it won't end up over the time
            paddingRight: 25
          } : {}}
                onLayout={(e) => {
                  let {height} = e.nativeEvent.layout

                  // if height is less than 30px, then we are dealing with a single line of content
                  if (height < 30) {
                    this.setState({'oneLine': true})
                  }
                }}>

            {this.renderContent(comment)}

          </View>

          <Text
            style={[styles.muted,
              {
                color: constants.FJMUTEDLIGHT,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                fontSize: 12,
                marginBottom: -5,
                // If one line, move the time up - there is enough space
                marginTop: this.state.oneLine ? -10 : 2
              }]}>{moment.utc(comment.created).local().format('HH:mm')}</Text>
        </View>
```

If we have a single line it still possible that the text will end up behind the time, so that's why I'm applying a right padding on the Text of 25 px. This breaks long lines and we end up with a view like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have spend all evening thinking about this issue. Searched all topic here and I didn't managed to find a solution. Then when I almost went to bed tired and disappointed I have invented the solution I am very proud to share with all pour souls.

Simple as 2 + 2. You just need to add string with some characters to the end of every message you've got. I use such string: '____'. And of course absolute position for timestamp. Here is part of my code:

```
      <Text style={styles.messageText}>
        {item.message}
        <Text style={{ color: 'transparent' }}>{' ' + '______'}</Text>
      </Text>
      <View style={styles.timeContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.timeText}>{formatTime(new Date(item.date))}</Text>
        <MaterialCommunityIcons name="check-all" color={COLORS.green} size={15} style={{ marginLeft: 2 }} />
      </View>


  [enter image description here][1]messageText: {
    color: COLORS.darkText,
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  timeContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 5,
    right: 3,
    width: 60,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
```

I define width of timestamp as 60 and just calibrate number of these spaces '_'. It depends on fonts, maybe you will need more or less of them. Also important to place this symbols **inside** your main  with message text. And to add a real whitespace ' ' before this additional symbols.
It works just like in telegram or other pro apps - brilliant! Check screenshot below.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iglcf.png