# react-native customize text elipsis to add "More" after elipsis

Tags: react-native

Following is from instagram which is known for using react-native

As you can see there is a text (더보기, which means `More`) after the elipsis (...)
How can I simulate that too?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have a more button or just the text at the end ?

Comment: `... more` as a text is fine

Answer (score 1):

Well, that is one of those things that on the surface looks easy enough, but actually is a complicated endeavor.

Due to this thing over here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22811 you won't be able to nest the `<Text>` tag and use the numberOfLines prop to achieve what you want.

In the past I've tried to deal with something similar: [React Native chat bubble flexbox similar to whatsapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154111/react-native-chat-bubble-flexbox-similar-to-whatsapp)

Back then there was no onTextLayout function(or at least I didn't know about it). The onTextLayout callback on the Text component gives you a line prop. The line is an array that contains information about every line of text.
You could use this to place the more button where you want.

```
const MoreInfo = text => {
  const [moreLeft, setMoreLeft] = React.useState(0)
  const [moreTop, setMoreTop] = React.useState(0)
  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
      <Text
        numberOfLines={2}
        ellipsizeMode={"tail"}
        onTextLayout={({ nativeEvent: { lines } }) => {
          const width = lines[lines.length - 1].width
          const height = lines[lines.length - 1].y

          setMoreTop(height)
          setMoreLeft(width)
        }}
      >
        {text}
      </Text>
      <Text
        style={{
          backgroundColor: "white",
          position: "absolute",
          left: moreLeft - 30,
          top: moreTop,
        }}
      >
        ... More
      </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Obviously the above implementation is not perfect. As you can see I just fake the ... by placing them in the More button. Sometimes it looks good, othertimes it cuts off the last letter in the string in the middle. But it serves to show the direction you need to go to solve this.

Some ideas:
inspect the lines array - if it has 2 lines is the last line width smaller than the first line width. Will your "More" text fit in the width difference? If yes, then just set the left position to the width.
if the second line is as long as the first one, then the ellepsis is at the end and you'll need to resort to the "... More" trick.

Comment: He has asked just to add the text,so replacing the last few letters of the text based on the lines array would work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick workaround. Create a function which takes text as an argument and show truncated text with a more button. Upon click, we will render full text with a less button.

```
const MoreLessComponent = ({ truncatedText, fullText }) => {
  const [more, setMore] = React.useState(false);
  return (
    <Text>
      {!more ? `${truncatedText}...` : fullText}
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setMore(!more)}>
        <Text>{more ? 'less' : 'more'}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </Text>
  );
};

const MoreInfo = (text, linesToTruncate) => {
  const [clippedText, setClippedText] = React.useState(false);
  return clippedText ? (
    <MoreLessComponent truncatedText={clippedText} fullText={text} />
  ) : (
    <Text
      numberOfLines={linesToTruncate}
      ellipsizeMode={'tail'}
      onTextLayout={(event) => {
        //get all lines
        const { lines } = event.nativeEvent;
        //get lines after it truncate
        let text = lines
          .splice(0, linesToTruncate)
          .map((line) => line.text)
          .join('');
        //substring with some random digit, this might need more work here based on the font size
        //
        setClippedText(text.substr(0, text.length - 9));
      }}>
      {text}
    </Text>
  );
};
```

Now call it like this

```
<View>
        {MoreInfo('Change code in the editor and watch it change on your phone! Save to get a shareable url.')}
      </View>
```

Here is the snack https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/react-native-more-less

Comment: thanks, the hard part is though we don't know what are the right amount of characters to use for given device.. there are many different devices that will show different # of characters in a line

Comment: Updated, should work with all sizes. You might have to adjust it with your setup though.

Comment: close.. but the Text will occupy less than full width because 'more' will take up whole column (not just the last line)

Comment: Right, This can be sorted, I adjusted my answer. Here is snack https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/react-native-more-less